# Change fill color of svg path based on background color of table cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, svg

I have a table with loads of data and only the last column has a background color based on risk score ie. green or red or orange...

I then have an svg map, which i would like to color the countries according to their risk score.

How can i change the fill color of an svg path (which has an id) based on the background color of a table cell (which only has a class)?

I don't know much about javascript or jquery, but am willing to try out and learn.

Thanks, here's some snippets of the code:

table:

```
<tr class="row-2" role="row">
  <td class="column-1">Rating<td>
</tr>
```

map:

```
<g id="landmarks">
   <path id="za" d="...pathnumbers..." class="clickable" style="fill: rgb(221, 51, 51);"></path>
</g>
```

Comment: Some markup showing the structure of the problem would help.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You really need to make some attempts and let us help you with problems. But at least post the code you have for starters, and we will see what we can do. See the [How to ask page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help in improving your questions in the future.

Comment: maybe i looked at this from a too complicated perspective, what i basically want is to set the fill color of the path to be the same as the background color of the td... (so if the td's color changes, the path color changes with it)

Comment: Give the path the same class as the td, set the fill and the background-color to be the same in the CSS class.